# Mule Deployment Namespace issue in Cloud Hub Deployment

Tags: mulesoft

Mule Version 3.8.8

I am trying to deploy a mule zip package into the cloud hub platform, during the deployment I am getting below error although any point studio also getting the same error.

I have created namespace and its added mule-app.properties #salesforce.namespace=myNp123

```
null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'salesforce.namespace' in string value "${salesforce.namespace}__"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.util.SystemPropertyUtils.resolvePlaceholders(SystemPropertyUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.util.SystemPropertyUtils.resolvePlaceholders(SystemPropertyUtils.java:63)
    at org.mule.config.spring.parsers.specific.GlobalPropertyDefinitionParser.postProcess(GlobalPropertyDefinitionParser.java:42)
    at org.mule.config.spring.parsers.AbstractMuleBeanDefinitionParser.doParse(AbstractMuleBeanDefinitionParser.java:425)
    at
```

Comment: There is no Mule 3.8.8 released. Is it 3.8.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the line in a properties file starts with a `#` then it is a comment:

```
#salesforce.namespace=myNp123
```

You need to remove the comment

```
salesforce.namespace=myNp123
```

When deploying to CloudHub you should set the properties from mule-app.properties in [Runtime Manager / app / Setting / Properties tab](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.8/configuring-properties#setting-properties-values-in-runtime-manager).

Comment: Thanks, Aled now the application is deployed successfully in cloud hub